# Hokuyo laser intermittent and not scanning entire area

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I added 2 lasers to my robot, one on the left and the other on the right with the intention of combining both scans into one to perform gmapping. Both lasers are positioned near the base of the robot to detect the presence of street kerbs in the mapping process. I am aware gmapping is used for indoors mapping but I'm experimenting with this approach.

The following is the xacro code that generates the right side hokuyo laser:

```
<xacro:macro name="laser_right">
    <gazebo reference="hokuyo_link_right">
        <sensor type="ray" name="head_hokuyo_sensor">
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <visualize>false</visualize>
        <update_rate>20</update_rate>
        <ray>
            <scan>
                <horizontal>
                    <samples>720</samples>
                    <resolution>1</resolution>
                    <min_angle>-1.570796</min_angle>
                    <max_angle>1.570796</max_angle>
                </horizontal>
            </scan>
            <range>
                <min>0.10</min>
                <max>10.0</max>
                <resolution>0.05</resolution>
            </range>
            <noise>
                <type>gaussian</type>
                <mean>0.0</mean>
                <stddev>0.01</stddev>
            </noise>
        </ray>
        <plugin name="gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
            <topicName>/scan_right</topicName>
            <frameName>hokuyo_link_right</frameName>
        </plugin>
        </sensor>
    </gazebo>

    <!-- Hokuyo Laser -->
    <link name="hokuyo_link_right">
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>

        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://rrbot_description/meshes/hokuyo.dae"/>
            </geometry>
        </visual>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="1e-5" />
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <joint name="laser_joint_right" type="fixed">
        <origin xyz="0.0 -0.27 -0.20" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <parent link="chasis"/>
        <child link="hokuyo_link_right"/>
    </joint>
</xacro:macro>
```

The scan as visualized in rviz shows the laser from both hukoyos as very intermitent and do not span the space on the right side of the robot. Shown below is the scan from the right side laser:

[image: image description]

I experiemted with the RPY values of the laser joint (perhaps the x-axis of the joint needed to be turned in the direction of the scan area), but that did not work.

I would appreciate some help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373972/hokuyo-laser-intermittent-and-not-scanning-entire-area/) by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2021-03-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-03-15**:
Since your field of view is set to +/- pi/2, I would guess that you do want the x-axis pointed to the right as you said (set yaw = -pi/2 in `laser_joint_right`).  What happened when you tried that?

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2021-03-17**:
@Tryan: Thank you for your response.
Using pi/2 as the yaw value as you suggested gives me a full semi-circle of laser scans on the right-hand side of the robot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to @tryan, I was able to adjust my scan radius by adjusting the YAW value of joint origins. Example below:

```
<joint name="laser_joint_right" type="fixed">
 <origin xyz="0.0 -0.25 -0.20" rpy="0 0 -${3.14/2}"/>
 . . .
</joint>
```

That gave me a full semi-circle laser radius on the tight hand side of my robot.

Also, I discovered the reason for the gittery intermittent lasers as shown in the image in my question above.
The sensor name was the same for both lasers. They needed to be unique.
Both left and right laser used `<sensor type="ray" name="head_hokuyo_sensor">` in the gazebo reference data.

I changed it to the following:

```
<sensor type="ray" name="head_hokuyo_sensor_right">
```

And I also altered the second laser on the left of the robot to:

```
<sensor type="ray" name="head_hokuyo_sensor_left">
```

This make the laser scans stable.

---

Originally posted by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) with karma: 247 on 2021-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1